# Panel not scrolling to the next components when it's in a scrollpane

Tags: java, swing, layout, jpanel, jscrollpane

i made the panel implement scrollable as well so it can scroll easily it still does not work.

here's a picture, and the jscrollpane that circulates a panel is in the middle : [image: http://puu.sh/9PFl2/5f824e88c6.png]

so when i try to scroll down, it just shows the components lagging and the components below do not load, i tested this with a system.out.println() when a button is clicked and the last gave off the same number which is 5 meaning its the same number.

here's my scrollpane class :

```
    public BackupsStage(){
        setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
        setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
        getViewport().setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        setViewportBorder(new LineBorder(Color.RED));
        panel = new BackupPanel();
        getViewport().add(panel);
        setBounds(5, 125, 985, 280);
        setVisible(false);
        current = this;
}
```

and here is my panel class :

```
    private class BackupPanel extends JPanel implements Scrollable{
    public BackupPanel() {
        setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 1));
    }
    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredScrollableViewportSize() {
        return super.getPreferredSize();
    }

    @Override
    public int getScrollableUnitIncrement(Rectangle visibleRect, int orientation, int direction) {
        return 100;
    }

    @Override
    public int getScrollableBlockIncrement(Rectangle visibleRect, int orientation, int direction) {
        return 16;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean getScrollableTracksViewportWidth() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean getScrollableTracksViewportHeight() {
        return true;
    }
}
```

here is my code that i use to add to the panel :

```
  public static void loadBackupOntoStage(String username,int hour,int minute, int backupNum){
    JButton revert = new JButton("Revert " + username + " to this backup");
    revert.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 9));
    revert.setFocusPainted(false);
   // revert.setVisible(false);
    panel.add(revert);
    revert_buttons.put(String.valueOf(backupNum - 1),revert);

    JLabel label = new JLabel("Backup created " + hour + " hours and " + minute + " minutes ago");
    label.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 14));
    label.setForeground(Color.DARK_GRAY);
    panel.add(label);
   // label.setVisible(false);
    backups.put(String.valueOf(backupNum - 1),label);

    JSeparator hsep = new JSeparator(JSeparator.HORIZONTAL);
   // hsep.setVisible(false);
    panel.add(hsep);
    current.setVisible(true);
    revert.addActionListener(e -> {
        System.out.print(backupNum - 1);
        String answer = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(
                FullMode.current
                , "Please type REVERT to confirm reverting " + username + " to this backup.\nThere is no going back after this."
                , "Reverting"
                , JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE

        );
        if (answer.equalsIgnoreCase("revert")) {
            // todo
        }
    });
}
```

so what am i doing wrong?

oh maybe you should know that the scrollpane is set in its place by setBounds, using a null layout.

Answer (score 3):

Why are you extending JScrollPane? I would avoid doing that if I were you, and most especially, I would not change the viewport's layout. That's what is likely screwing you up.

Also your call to `setBounds(...)` suggests that some of your GUI uses a `null` layout, another thing that can royal mess up JScrollPanes and GUI's in general as they make for very inflexible GUI's that while they might look good on one platform look terrible on most other platforms or screen resolutions and that are very difficult to update and maintain. You will want to avoid using these if at all possible.

Comment: i removed the viewport's layout but now the jscrollpane just forces all components to keep getting smaller as they increase which is eliminating the scrollbar to appear, here is what i meant : http://puu.sh/9PGgU/a0f904d942.png

Comment: @user3637864: This question is becoming a `"guess what the code I'm not showing you is doing"` type question. Please fix this by creating and posting your [minimal code example program](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for us to review, test, and possibly fix. Yes this will require a bit of extra effort on your part, but it will be well worth it in the end, as you'll likely get a useful answer quickly if you can do this.

Comment: +1 for NOT using a null layout and NOT changing the layout of the viewport. @user3637864, Scrollbars will appear automatically when the "preferred size" of the panel is greater than the "size" of the scroll pane. There is no need for you to implement the `Scrollable` interface. Just use a proper layout manager and the preferred size will be calculated automatically. If you are dynamically adding components you need to `revalidate()` the panel so the preferred size can be recalculated.

Comment: @user3637864: please have another look at the [mcve requirements link](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) as it will require more effort on your part. The link will tell you exactly what is required to satisfy the mcve requirements.